# saving domdocument with $VAR$ as form action

Tags: php, html, domdocument

As the title suggests, i am trying to save a domdocument. This domdocument has a action, with the value $VAR$ however, upon saving of the domdocument the $ dollar signs are escaped.
How can i prevent that it is being escaped?
Regards,
Michel
edit code:

```
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);    
    $body = $xpath->query('//body')->item(0);
    $form = $doc->createElement('form');
    $form->setAttribute('action', '$PORTAL_ACTION$');
    $form->setAttribute('method', 'post');
    $p = $doc->createElement('p');
    $p->setAttribute('style','text-align:center;');
    $b = $doc->createTextNode('Wifi code:');
    $p->appendChild($b);
    $inputvoucher = $doc->createElement('input');
    $inputvoucher->setAttribute('name', 'auth_voucher');
    $inputvoucher->setAttribute('type', 'text');
    $p->appendChild($inputvoucher);
    $inputredirurl = $doc->createElement('input');
    $inputredirurl->setAttribute('name', 'redirurl');
    $inputredirurl->setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    $inputredirurl->setAttribute('value', '$PORTAL_REDIRURL$');
    $p->appendChild($inputredirurl);
    $inputsubmit =  $doc->createElement('input');
    $inputsubmit->setAttribute('type','submit');
    $inputsubmit->setAttribute('name', 'accept');
    $inputsubmit->setAttribute('value', 'Continue');
    $p->appendChild($inputsubmit);
    $form->appendChild($p);
    $body->appendChild($form);
    return urldecode($doc->saveHTML());
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: `php > $d=new DOMDocument(); $e=$d->createElement('element'); $e->setAttribute('a','$xyz$'); $d->appendChild($e); echo $d->saveHTML();` returns `<element a="$xyz$"></element>` unescaped, you do more than you show (PHP 5.6.8)

Comment: $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $doc->formatOutput = true;
        //error onderdrukken voor lege html(default page geeft een error op multiple id's)
        $doc->loadHTML($html);

Comment: it seems that the action attribute is internally validated by the domdocument. Has nothing to do with my code.

Comment: @MichelKok, you are right, try saveXML() then instead of saveHTML() might suit you better, but since the action is in fact normally an URL, escaping makes sense

Comment: but when i save as xml there is no body tag...